# Meaning of the Characters and Signature on Teapot

Tags: translation, meaning, characters, character-identification

I recently found a red clay teapot (potentially a Yixing, but probably a fake) that seems somewhat modern, but I can't read the writing that's on them. Anyone want to take a crack at it? Apologies if I took the bottom signature picture wrong! Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!
[image: Bottom signature]
[image: First lid writing]
[image: Second lid writing]
[image: First teapot side writing]
[image: Second teapot side writing]
[image: Side of teapot signature?]
[image: Under lid seal]

Answer (score 4):

1- 袁玲鳳制 - made by Yuan Lingfeng

2, 3- 祝福 - blessing

4, 5- 茶道 - Dao of tea

6- 劉石林 - Liu Shilin

7- 玲鳳 - Ling Feng

Comment: That’s **袁玲**鳳 as the name

Comment: Thanks, I searched " ?珍鳳制 teapot" and 珍鳳 teapot did show up